# Wrapping a React Hook return value is causing a render loop

Tags: reactjs

I am using https://react-hook-form.com/api/ to hold values and perform validations on some form controls in one React functional component. I need to upload the values the user inputs in the form controls as soon as they change, so I designed a simple component that overrides the `setValue` and `registerFields` like this:

```
export function wrapFormWithListeners(formsObject, options = {}) {
  /** @type {Object.<string, Observable>} */
  let changes = {};
  /** @type {Object.<string, Subject>} */
  let changeEmitters = {};
  let registrationsSubject = new ReplaySubject();

  return {
    ...formsObject,
    register: createRegisterProxy(
      formsObject.register,
      changes,
      changeEmitters,
      registrationsSubject,
      options
    ),
    setValue: createSetValueProxy(formsObject.setValue, changeEmitters),
    changes,
    registrations: registrationsSubject
  };
}
```

I am calling that wrapper function un-conditionally on my functional component like this:

```
function MyComponent({ prop }) {
  const form = useForm();
  const modifiedForm = wrapFormWithListeners(form);
  const {
    register,
    errors,
    getValues,
    setValue,
    triggerValidation,
    clearError,
    reset
  } = modifiedForm;
}
```

My problem is that whenever I destructure the `modifiedForm` object React starts looping the render over and over again. I know it's not a problem with my component because it doesn't use any React API calls, and calling the `wrapFormWithListeners` function without accessing any of the members in the returned object makes the render work fine; In other words this makes the component work, though I lose the upload functionality:

```
function MyComponent({ prop }) {
  const form = useForm();
  const modifiedForm = wrapFormWithListeners(form);
  const {
    register,
    errors,
    getValues,
    setValue,
    triggerValidation,
    clearError,
    reset
  } = form;
}
```

Is there something I am missing about how React may be understanding my function as a user hook or something?

I am using `"react": "^16.12.0"`

Comment: 2 things to start with. where are you calling `MyComponent`? and you are destructuring prop `({ prop })` but you aren't using it

Comment: @RedBaron The prop is just a redacted variable name, we use that in another part of the component that is not included in the sample, as it doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem. `MyComponent` wraps a https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/ component, toggling it according to a prop passed from the parent component.